# TypeScript generic function for building instance of Distributive Type

Tags: typescript

### Code Sample

I have the following code:

```
type DataFor = {
    "a" : number,
    "b" : string
}

export type Ops = keyof DataFor

// distributive hack
type Request<Op extends Ops> = Op extends Ops ? {
  tag: Op,  data: DataFor[Op]
} : never;

function runA(data: number) { /* ... */ }
function runB(data: string) { /* ... */ }

function example1(req: Request<Ops>) {
    // typechecks, thanks to the distributive hack
    if(req.tag === "a") {
        runA(req.data);
    } else if(req.tag === "b") {
        runB(req.data);
    }  
}

function example2<Op extends Ops>(op: Op, data: DataFor[Op]) {
    const request: Request<Op> = { tag: op, data };
}
```

I was able to use the "distributive hack" to make `example1` typecheck, but `example2` produces the following type error:

```
Type '{ tag: keyof DataFor; data: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'Request<Op>'.
```

### Guess

My guess is that this has to do with the fact that `Op extends Ops` does not sufficiently restrict the type, since we could have `Op = "a"|"b"` as a valid choice.

### Question

Is there a similar distributive hack for `example2` that will allow me to write a generic function for creating instances of the `Request`?

Comment: use `as Request<Op>;`

Answer (score 0):

You may

```
type Pairs = {[K in Ops]: [op: K, data: DataFor[K]] & ({_?: Request<K>})}[Ops]

function example2<Pair extends Pairs>(...[op, data]: Pair) {
    const request: Request<Pair[0]> = { tag: op, data  };
}
```

to make distributeg generic function

but you will need `as Request<Op>` cast anyways

Comment: Unfortunately your example gives the same error, `Type '{ tag: "a" | "b"; data: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'Request<Pair[0]>`.  I am looking for a solution that does not use `as`, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Without the intermediate `tag` property

```
type DataFor = {
    "a" : number,
    "b" : string
}
export type Ops = keyof DataFor
function runA(data: number) { /* ... */ }
function runB(data: string) { /* ... */ }
// distributive hack
type Args<Op extends Ops> = Op extends Ops ? {
  op: Op,  data: DataFor[Op]
} : never;
function example2<Op extends Ops>({op,data}:Args<Op>) {
   if(op === "a") {
        runA(data);
    } else if(op === "b") {
        runB(data);
    }      
}
example2({op:"a",data:1});
example2({op:"b",data:""});
example2({op:"b",data:2});// error
```

Without requiring the extra syntax of passing an object with properties is also possible:

```
type Args3<Op extends Ops> = Op extends Ops ? [
  op: Op,  data: DataFor[Op]
 ] : never;
function example3<Op extends Ops>(...[op,data]:Args3<Op>) {
   if(op === "a") {
        runA(data);
    } else if(op === "b") {
        runB(data);
    }      
}

example3("a",1);
example3("b","");
example3("b",2);// error
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAxA9gJygXigbwFBSFQBEcxUAXFAHYCuAtgEYRoA0BRxj5VAzsGgCW1AOZ4AvnggAPMOmBRQkKAHkwvLFADWEECgBmsBMnR59tagGNgglNShoLAQQAUAE2NU6TFgEpcUAD0AFRQAHQRUMGBUJLmVjZ2DhYAQu6eUPxCov44QaERYVExkoExboJZgoy0NgBu0AAWcJZaeErQTmgivAA8alAywBDUbhpqvAB8mgNDI2Oq6lAA-LgcKGBUaqyEHohU8IioaADaagC6EpQ0EA1oANxmFta29jJw9GAANhAATP1gQbSYajcbqSYuHAbVh7ODiChdHoAya5DhQQT6FwbLCYbCkYioohE5LUVyw3yPIniQZfXjQDFYwG4vHcQnEwiOahpcmUojU4kSPBSaQfb5-SEbCj4mGeACM4gpwtFP1+Es2XGIMv2xGICse70+KrVUu4WrgFF+erKgzQaFMQo6UERvAAzACgSCFhNpthZsD5mCNKsTutNosdlBYQdjMczmBLlBztdqLcWI8nglXkDlRA3X7PYGIYUTtDYecEd1Xci2ejMdjmSQyDXiZyycZFVSaXTa4ycSyCWt2RzUulEB2+ezBUrDbmXNLZYqDWKXXPTTrFyKZyuNaxfhTrSw7Wg8EA)